# Graphs that suffice being a bipartite and also complement of paths?

Tags: graph-theory

The question asks for graphs that may suffice being the intersection of A{Bipartite Graph} & B{Complement of Path}

The way I understand this question is to find a complement of the bipartite graph that constitutes a path.

I know that every bipartite graph has paths in it but what about the complement of paths? Since Bipartite doesn't have to be complete and connected, I believe every bipartite can have it's complement being a path. So the answer is all bipartite suffice this condition.

I'm new to Graph Theory, so I'm not so sure if my logic here is sound.Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking "Which bipartite graphs are the complements of paths?" then the answer is certainly **not** "All bipartite graphs." For example, $K_{3,3}$ is a bipartite graph:

[image: k33]

but it's not the complement of a path, because its complement is a graph with two cycles:

[image: 2k3]

In general, if either side of the bipartition is too large, the complement of the graph will contain a cycle. So you only have to check bipartite graphs in which both sides of the bipartition are small, and there will only be a few cases that work. Your answer will be a finite (and small) set of graphs.

(And a more promising direction to go in is actually posing the problem differently: "Which complements of paths are bipartite?" There are a lot fewer different graphs that are complements of paths to check, than there are bipartite graphs.)